# C get contents of file recursivley

Tags: c, file, recursion, printing

I am trying to print out the contents of every file given a directory recursively. I have some logical error in my code and I can't figure out where it's going wrong.

Go through directory/subdirectories and get filename:

```
char filename[500], filepath[500];

void listdir(char *dir)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *name;
    struct stat statbuf;

    if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"cannot open directory: %s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    chdir(dir);

    while((name = readdir(dp)) != NULL) 
    {
        if(lstat(name->d_name, &statbuf) == 0)
        {
            if(statbuf.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
            {
                /* Found a directory, but ignore . and .. */
                if(strcmp(".", name->d_name) == 0 || strcmp("..", name->d_name) == 0)
                    continue;

                // Directory name
                int len = strlen(filepath);
                strcat(filepath, name->d_name);
                strcat(filepath, "/");

                /* Recurse at a new indent level */
                listdir(name->d_name);

                filepath[len] = '\0';
            }
            else
            {
                // Filename
                strcpy(filename, filepath);
                strcat(filename, name->d_name);

                // Prevent double printing
                if(file[strlen(filename) - 1] != '~')
                    readFile(filename);
            }
        }
    }

    chdir("..");
    closedir(dp);
}
```

Open/Read file contents:

```
void readFile(char *filepath)
{
    char ch;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen(filepath, "r");

    if(file)
    {
        while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
            printf("%c", ch);

        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
    listdir(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

So if I run the program like this `./fileread ~/Desktop` and I have this on the Desktop:

> Songs.txt, test/test.txt, test/random.txt

It will print out the contents of Songs.txt, but won't print out anything inside the test folder. If I take out "Prevent double printing" line, then it will print out the contents of Songs.txt twice and still not print out anything inside the test folder.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

---

**UPDATED**

I added local strings:

```
void getdir(char *dir)
{
    char *direct;
    char filepath[250];

    ...

    direct = malloc(strlen(dir) + strlen(name->d_name) + 2);
    strcpy(direct, dir);
    strcat(direct, "/");
    strcat(direct, name->d_name);

    getdir(direct);
    free(direct);
}
else
{
    // Concatenate file name
    strcpy(filepath, dir);
    strcat(filepath, "/");
    strcat(filepath, name->d_name);

    if(filepath[strlen(filepath) - 1] != '~')
        readFile(filepath);
}
```

This seems to work great. If there's anything I shouldn't do, please let me know. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You are fiddling with global strings, so when the recursion returns to the previous/ lower levels, they are no longer the same. You need to duplicate a locally defined string, work with, and pass that.

Comment: I would be tempted to printf the 'dir' parameter at the start, no matter whether the opendir()succeeds or not.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh.. missed that, probably because it's a weird thing to do - can't  see any advantage over locals:(

Comment: Also, not sure what that chdir() call is for.  Archaic concepts like 'current  directory' are best forgotten about.

Comment: ...especially when the filename is concatenated to the file path anyway?

Comment: Yeah.  Maybe the idea was to economise on stack buffers.  I've used languages with 'real' string types for a long time now and so have forgotten to worry about such matters:)

Comment: Yes, when you handle recursive functions you have either to manage local variables or - if global - to use a stack, so that you can "pop" when leaving.

Comment: Also, OP, those globals totally fu.. foul up your  thread-safely.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I updated the code above. I think followed everything you guys said.